# Galera preciso de uma ajuda com Php e Mysql

Tags: php

Eu estou criando um site/blog em Php, eu já fiz um sistema de buscas em php e mysql, mas eu estou com uma duvida, já pesquisei sobre o assunto e não acho, eu gostaria de saber, como retornar uma consulta no banco de dados em links, por exemplo, eu botar um campo pro usuário fazer uma pesquisa, e os resultados virem em formas de links, como por exemplo títulos de postagens, não quero que ninguém faça o código pra mim, apenas me diga como eu posso fazer isso.

Comment: então pode descrever melhor como esta organizado seu banco de dados?
Pelo que entendi você quer fazer uma consulta e retornar em "formas de links", então você precisa primeiro de uma query para capturar os dados do banco de dados e dentro do seu banco de dados deve ter uma coluna em alguma tabela que representa esses links, seja ele um endereço relativo ou absoluto.
Se descrevesse melhor como está seu banco de dados, posso te ajudar melhor...

Comment: Coloca a parte do código, onde está o loop que retorna os dados em texto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em uma coluna de uma tabela no banco, salve os urls.

No `echo` da consulta coloque-o como valor do atributo `href` da tag `a`

> `echo ("<a href='".$row['link']."'>`

**Exemplo completo**

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

//$sql = "Sua Query";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Tabela"; //exemplo
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

> `echo ("<a href='".$row['link']."'>".$row['titulo']."</a><br>\n");`

```
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

**Exemplo:**

- Tabela

  [image: tabela]
- Resultado

  [image: resultado da consulta]
- Código fonte

  [image: codigo fonte]